# Magento 2: Automatically generate CSV file on every order

Tags: magento2, orders

I need to create a CSV file on every order I receive. 
How can I do this? Can you guys please suggest me a way to do this or an existing module that does that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to sync order data to another system?

Comment: No. I just need to automatically create a CSV from the last order. This file needs to be uploaded to the server

Comment: you can use `sales_order_place_after` observer and get required data in CSV

Comment: Uhm, can you please tell me more about it?

Comment: please see my answer, I just get order data. you can put CSV logic based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! It's working

Comment: @GerardoSiano,  welcome :) and glad to know it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a small module, which will use event-observer feature of magento.
we will put an observer which will get trigger when any order will get placed!

create following files:

> app/code/Pawan/GenerateCSV/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Pawan_GenerateCSV',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Pawan/GenerateCSV/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pawan_GenerateCSV" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/GenerateCSV/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
   <event name='sales_order_place_after'>
        <observer
                name='sales_order_place_after'
                instance='Pawan\GenerateCSV\Observer\GenerateCSV'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pawan/GenerateCSV/Observer/GenerateCSV.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawan\GenerateCSV\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GenerateCSV implements ObserverInterface
{
 protected $_objectManager;
 private $logger;
 private $productFactory;


  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
  ) {
      $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
      $this->logger = $logger;
      $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
    $this->logger->info($order_id);
    $this->logger->info("observer working");  

  }
}
```

**Explanation:** Now you have all Order data in observer class, form here you can get order, product information and can get data in CSV

Hope above will help!

Comment: Hi Pawan, How can I get the item id, quantity and price from this?

Comment: You can get all items by `$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();`. in foreach loop , you can get item price, id etc..

Comment: I am already trying with  `foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
 {
 $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
 $product_qty[] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
 $product_price[] = $item->getPrice(); }` but not able to get the price.

Comment: If you are not getting price, You may need to load Order OR inject `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository` in your observer and get Order like `$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);`

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this below link -**

https://magecomp.com/blog/automatically-generate-csv-file-on-every-order-magento-2/